# Template Generator

Tags: c#, text-files

I have a text-file called txtRaw.txt with Raw data in the format:

```
Oranges And Cucumber
Oranges And Apples
Orange And Kiwi
Apples And Mangoes
Apples And Bananas
Apples And Strawberry
Bananas And Wall-nuts
Bananas And Water Melons
Bananas And Grapes
```

I have a second text-file called Template.txt:

```
I went to buy **num0** at the grocery store.
The weather was starting to get cold, so I got thirsty.
I did not want to purchase **num1** so I had to get something else.
I ended up buying **num2** and was done for the day.
```

I am trying to create a program that can take the raw data and use the Template.txt to create a 3rd file that has output like this:

```
I went to buy **Oranges And Cucumber** at the grocery store.
The weather was starting to get cold, so I got thirsty.
I did not want to purchase **Oranges And Apples** so I had to get something else.
I ended up buying Orange And Kiwi and was done for the day.
I went to buy **Apples And Mangoes** at the grocery store.
The weather was starting to get cold, so I got thirsty.    
I did not want to purchase **Apples And Bananas** so I had to get something else.
I ended up buying **Apples And Strawberry** and was done for the day.
I went to buy **Bananas And Wall-nuts** at the grocery store.
The weather was starting to get cold, so I got thirsty.
I did not want to purchase **Bananas And Water Melons** so I had to get something else.
I ended up buying **Bananas And Grapes** and was done for the day.
```

Is there an existing software that can do this? I have experience with C#, so if no software exists then what would be the most efficient (memory and processing speed) way to write this code? As of right now I would just create an array that I read the raw file in. Then I would ask the user how many lines each **set** in txtRaw has (Orange is a set, Apples is a set, Bananas is a set, so each fruit has 3 sets). The template would then be replicated for each set and pasted into a 2nd array. Then I would go through each element of the template array and replace the num# text with an element from the rawData array.

I don't know if this is efficient, so I am mainly asking for suggestions on how to program this effectively.

Comment: I think in .NET world, the most common template engine is T4: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx. Though it has a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, if you're just looking for a quick way to get an output and this process won't need to be repeated, you can try using MS Word's mailings feature.  Just put the raw data in the contact fields and then type out your template using the contact variables.  Produce your documents.  Done.  (In this option, you can import your raw data, but you might need to turn it into a csv file or something first.

Any form application can probably do this; then you'd just fill the form out (automatically) using your raw data.

Or if you want to program something, you could read the lines of your raw data file into an array of strings and then have it output your template while iterating through that array.

Comment: The problem I see with the mailing feature is that it requires your sets to be organized by columns. All I have is 1 column and the number of elements in each set is 3 this time but could be 4 or 5+ next time. For sets in one column the mailing feature wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There will be very simple code for this

`var items=System.IO.File.ReadLines("PathToFile1");
var text=System.IO.File.ReadAllText("PathToFile1");
var optput=string.Format("text",items)`

For this you need to Instead of using num0, num1 use {0},{1} and so forth. This you can change while you store file2 or in code by using Regex replacement.

Comment: In order for this to work don't I need to manually replicate my template for each set inside items and then increment a number in my template for each item?

Comment: I guess your question already has increamented numbers for each item like num0, num1, num2 etc. I'm just asking you to use {0}, {1}, {2} and so on in it's place. And if you do not have access to do it in file itself you can do it in code using Regex replace.